# Query to choose value closest to divisible number

Tags: sql

I have a weird query.  I am creating a vehicle maintenance database.  Each vehicle has different maintenance cycles at 250, 500, 1000, and 2000.  so when a user pulls up to a vehicle and enters the mileage it needs to know what is the next maintenance cycle.

Here is an example. so the vehicle would have 1150 miles the next cycle would be 1250.  I have a table that says there are 250, 500, 1000, and 2000 cycles but I don't have anything for the 1250 or 1500 or 1750 because they are the same as 250...

So what would I do to pick the next maintenance cycle? I am thinking do a division of the top number and then the lower numbers and pick the one that is closer to a whole number but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also show sample data, so we know how the data is represented.

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe you can try something like this:
(Floor(miles/maintenacecycle)+1)*maintenancecycle

This should give you always the next stop, depending on the maintenancecycle of each single vehicle